# Django query on a link table generated from a many to many relashionship

Tags: django, django-models

Here is an example of a part of a `models.py` file that manages recipes and ingredients:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)
```

I heard that Django will automatically create a link table using the name of the app, then the referencing model and the model being referenced, all in lower case. Let's say that the app in my example is called `cookbook` then the name of the linked table would be `cookbook_recipe_ingredient`, am I right so far?

So, let's suppose I now want to query this linked table from some sort of script at the bottom of the `models.py` file, to make automated treatments in the database. In this case, it would be to list all recipes containing peanuts. If it was an SQL database, a simple query like this would suffice:

```
select distinct recipe from cookbook_recipe_ingredient where ingredient = 'peanut'
```

What would be the Django way of making such a query on such a link table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following django docs ([many_to_many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)):

```
Recipe.objects.filter(ingredients__name='peanut')
```

This gets you every recipe with peanut as ingredient name.

PS: your SQL query won't work. Table `cookbook_recipe_ingredient` contains two foreign keys - one is id of `Ingredient` and the second is id of `Recipe`. You need to correct it.

Comment: Indeed it seems to work. I haven't thought about querying the recipes. I might still be in a SQL state of mind. Anyway, thanks for the answer.